# Compressing data sent to an ASMX web service

Tags: c#, .net, web, compression, asmx

I have an old style .NET ASMX (SOAP/XML) webservice that is used to upload data to a central service with a very simple and lightweight ack response.  This has been in place for years and has worked perfectly well.

However, usage has now changed a little and the overall size of the payload data being sent has increased to the point where it is no longer feasible/reliable to send the data uncompressed.

So the question is: how can I enable compression on the data sent from the client to the webservice.

Having Google'd around there are countless pages regarding compressing the response from the service, however I need to compress the request.

Bear in mind that this has to remain as an ASMX and has to remain on .NET 2

EDIT : As an interim measure I am manually compressing (GZIP) the payload data before it is sent and then uncompressing on the other side.  This works but I would prefer "traditional transport level" compression.

For example:

```
...
<soap:Body>
    <MessageData id="1234">
        <SenderIdentifier>foobar</SenderIdentifier>
        <Payload>....This is what is compressed (GZIP)....</Payload>
    </MessageData>
</soap:Body>
....
```

Comment: You explicitly want to compress the Request? Because you could also consider compressing whatever payload is in the Request, but leave the Request alone. This will be much easier to implement, because you don't mess with the actual Request/Response. Obviously this assumes you are able to change both the implementation client-side and server-side.

Comment: This is what we are doing at the moment, running the payload through GZIP compression before sending and then uncompressing within the receiver.  This works but, if it is possible, I would like to use "transport level" compression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've blogged on that 3 years ago:

http://netpl.blogspot.com/2009/07/aspnet-webservices-two-way-response-and.html

Comment: Fantastic blog, answers everything I need! Work on your SEO, get the page ranked higher ;)

Comment: Thanks :) We use this particular solution in a production environment for 3 years and it behaves quite reliable.

Comment: It would have been fantastic if the fantastic blog still existed.

Comment: @mwardm: It exists, the page opens fine. Just redirects to newer domain.

Comment: I'll give you that, Wiktor - well done for maintaining internet continuity!  (About 10 hours ago I saw the redirect happen but got no response from the new domain.)